# How to redirect (301) search results page which do not return results

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I tried this:

```
<?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit; ?>
```

Not working. 
Javascript redirects are working but after all it's user-end redirect and not server-side. I was wondering how to do a 301 permanent redirect instead of showing 'no results found'.

Please also let me know where to place the code in search.php. (right now, I'm placing it right after `<?php else : ?>`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace old-page.php code with redirection code to new-page.php.
so in your case if you want to a new search.php code you should have two php files. First, the old-search.php which contains the following code, and then the new-search.php code which is the one that should be specified in the link.

---old-search.php---

```
<?php
// PHP permanent URL redirection
header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/new-search.php", true, 301);
exit();
?>
```

For more info (different ways) go to this [link](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/url-redirect.htm#301-redirect)

Comment: Not working. The gets stuck by that code, and the sidebar and footer is not loading.
P.S I'm placing code between "<?php else : ?>" and "<?php endif; ?>"

Comment: remove the exit() and try again.

Comment: Not working either. Same problem. Header loads, sidebar and footer doesn't load. No redirect happening.
Are you sure I should be placing this code between php else and php endif? Can you make it clear where exactly should I place your code in search.php? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

for page response like 404 and any other try this.

```
if(isset($imported_post)){
        wp_redirect($post_link, 301); exit;
    }
    else{ // No match, generate 404
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
}
```

Comment: Not working either. As I said in my above comment, I'm placing code between "<?php else : ?>" and "<?php endif; ?>" so that it will trigger if the search returns no results.